# Spring AOP @Pointcut and @Before yields IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am doing a springboot project that includes login and accounts. I am trying to `@Pointcut` all controller method calls and validate the login information, and `@Before` the pointcut to make sure the session exists. Hence the code:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthAspect {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(* show.xianwu.game.frisbeescorer.controller.*.*(..))")
    public void validateLogin(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // check the login information
    }

    @Before("validateLogin()")
    public void validateSession(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // check the session
    }
}
```

However, this yields `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]:  BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut`.

Deleting the `validateSession()` and `@Before` makes the `@Pointcut` work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove `JoinPoint` from your `@Pointcut` annotated method.

Comment: @Power_tile, please be so polite as to provide feedback to the comments and answers other users spent time on writing for your benefit here. Ideally, accept an adequate answer of your own choice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define a `JoinPoint` parameter in the pointcut. It only belongs in the advice method using the pointcut, not in the pointcut itself. You are not using it there anyway because a pointcut is never executed, the method is just a dummy to be decorated by the `@Poinctut` annotation. So what you want is this:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* show.xianwu.game.frisbeescorer.controller.*.*(..))")
public void validateLogin() {
    // check the login information
}
```

Besides (and unrelated to your problem), the `.*.*` is quite specific and only matches a method in a class which is exactly in package `show.xianwu.game.frisbeescorer.controller`. If you want to also include classes in subpackages, use the `..` syntax instead, in this case `show.xianwu.game.frisbeescorer.controller..*`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a Springboot-based project, I recommend you use Spring Security features or other authorization & authentication frameworks such as Shiro.

If you wish to use none of them anyway, you can use `@ModelAttributes` in a super class to invoke a method before any controller method is invoked.

```java
@Controller
public class ExampleController extends BaseController {...}
```

```java
public class BaseController {
    @ModelAttribute
    public void invokeBefore(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response) {
         // Check the auth info (e.g., Authorization header) of the request.
    }
}
```

Besides, to my experience, it is a bad practice to directly use `@Pointcut` in a SpringBoot application. Use a [customized Spring annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation) instead.

Comment: Authentication checks etc. do not belong in a controller they should either be in a filter which would execute long before anything else or applied through AOP. This breaks too easily. The only good thing is to use Spring Security which is a tried and tested framework, don't try to roll your own security solution.

Comment: True. I agree with M. Deinum on this. Typically, if the time allows, I prefer to have a separate gateway application where I can do authentication and authorization in filters. Even if I have to fit everything into one single Springboot application, I would use Shiro to filter the requests before any request lands onto controllers.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.